# MariaDB System Versioned Tables, Update queries causing duplicates

Tags: mariadb

I have just enabled system versioned tables on an existing system and am experiencing an oddity, not sure if it is a bug or if I am misunderstanding something.

I have a table called assets, in this table are some basic columns for details about an asset as well as some "cached" status columns. these status columns are updated when something changes and are things like "nextServiceDue" which is calculated based on a somewhat complex join that is not "quick", So I have decided to "cache" it for quickness.

Now, I am paranoid that there is a possibility that I have written a function somewhere that updates the asset but does not trigger the cache to be updated, so I have a cronjob set up to run a query at 2am to recalculate it for all assets.

99.9999% of the time, this affects 0 results. `Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.` but I have noticed when trying to "go back in time" with system version tables, that when I go back, it returns duplicate rows, if I go back 1 day, there will be 2 copies of an asset returned on a simple `SELECT * FROM assets` if I go back 2 days, it will return 3 and so on.

to test, I ran the update query again and then selected the exact same asset and an extra duplicate appeared. (so now 2 days returns 4 instead of 3).

(I have also noticed a 10% jump in mariadb backup size in the space of 2 days)

I am not sure what is going on and why it is duplicating in this way. if there are 0 rows updated in an update query, why is it creating these duplicates and why is it showing them to me, surely even if this DID happen, it should only show me the 1 row for each time point.

Sorry for the rambling, not sure how to explain it as I do not know what is going on.

Comment: It seems like I've stumbled on the same problem. Did you find any clues what's going on here? 

My analysis so far: The uniqness in System-versioned tables is ensured with the "old" primary key + row_end, but row_start isn't part of this automatically added uniq constraint. The duplicate entries I'm experiencing have the same ID and the same row_start while row_end differs (row_end of the previous version of a row is equivalent to the time of the update). It looks like row_start of the new version of a row isn't set properly.

Comment: Also regarding your question why there are even new entries when nothing is updated: This seems to be the (currently) expected behaviour since a new version of a row is created even if alle columns are unchanged. This was discussed in multiple MDEV issues and was changed at least once.

Comment: [MDEV-26783](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26783) discussing this was created just 4 hours ago, while the older MDEVs regarding this behaviour are linked in a comment on this MDEV. [MDEV-26778](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26778) regarding the duplicates was also created today.